# Не получается записать url в дата атрибут

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не получается записать url в дата атрибут.

html

```
   <div class="wrap-img">
      <div class="share-link-list social-likes">
            <li class="share-img fb" data-service="facebook"  data-media=""></li>
            <li class="share-img vk" data-service="vkontakte" data-media=""></li>
            <li class="share-img ok" data-service="odnoklassniki" data-media=""></li>
            <li class="share-img pin" data-service="pinterest" data-media=""></li>
            <li class="share-img tw" data-service="twitter" data-media=""></li>
      </div>
      <img alt="" src="/images/examle/example.jpg" >
   </div>
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("body").bind("click", ".share-img", function(){       
    var urlImg = $( this ).closest(".wrap-img").find('img').attr('src');
        $(".share-img").attr("data-media", 'http://mysite.example.ru' + urlImg);    

    });
});
```

Comment: точно, мой косяк

Comment: исправил, но все равно получается

Comment: для работы с `data-` атрибутами имеется метод `data()`, в данном случае использовать как `data('media', value)`

Comment: автор, а что вы вообще хотите сделать то?

Comment: я хочу вот  как тут  http://www.livemaster.ru/item/16743601-ukrasheniya-laure-keramicheskie-tsvety-broshi

Comment: `data()` пишет не в атрибуты а во внутренний кэш, он только читает из `data-`артибутов, и то не всегда. Если нужно чтобы гарантированно было в атрибутах то нужно использовать `attr`

Comment: На самом деле метод [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) в jquery не добавляет/изменяет значение атрибута. Он его считывает при первом доступе, и сохраняет у себя

Comment: у меня передает  http://mysite.example.ruundefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.wrap-img').each(function(){
    var urlImg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var siteUrl = 'http://example.ru'; 
    var fullUrl = siteUrl + urlImg;
    $( this ).find('.share-img').attr('data-media', fullUrl);


});
```